# Lxf to ldr - Chain is not converting

Tags: model, 3d, ldd, 3d-model, lego-mindstorms

I am converting a lego model to a **.ldr** file. However, the chain link models are not converted/present in the export!

Is there a way to export the chain models too?
Otherwise, how can I get their models into my **.ldr** file?

---

Here is a screen capture to show what's happening:

[image: Animation]